# Floating the NAV bumps it down

Tags: css-float, html, nav

When I try to "float" my navigation, it gets bumped down, sometimes a few pixels, sometimes a lot. If I make the parent display:inline; it will remove the bump, but the structure is all messed up. If I remove the float from the nav it is not bumped down, but again, the structure is not what I need. I tried position:absolute; and position:relative; for both the nav and the parent and it doesn't help. I tried placing a clear:both; all over the place to no avail.

(I tried searching here and the google, but I don't know enough about what I am doing wrong to find an answer)

Here is a screenshot of 2 sites I have this problem with. The first one has that yellow gap above it that I don't want, the second has a few pixels of black above the dark gray, kind of hard to see. (If I remove the floats the gaps go away, but the structure of the menu fails)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from using `display:inline-block;` where the browser automatically inserts a margin on the bottom of the element to allow for letter descenders. You can change your `display` to `:block;` if it will not break your layout. If not, you can add a negative margin to the bottom.

There are a few options here, that worked, depending on the layout I was using. Here are some that worked:

`margin-bottom:-3px;` or `margin-bottom:-4px;`

`margin-bottom:-0.15em;` worked too.